# What is the equivalent of viewWillAppear for NSDocument

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsdocument

I have a `NSDocument` based application with a nib that represents the visual document. As soon as the view Appeared I want to trigger some actions.

For a "normal" `UIViewController` I would simply override `viewDidAppear:`. However, `NSDocument` does not have this method, even though it has a view per document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSDocument` offers
`-(void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *)aController;` method.
I think this is what you are looking for.
The document window controllers are still accessible using `NSDocument`'s `windowControllers` method.

If you have more precise requirements on window appearing/disappearing, becoming key, etc..., you could handle that with [window notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSWindow), or [window delegation system](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

There's `-[NSDocument showWindows]` which could be useful to add some custom logic on the end of.